# cannot click button in changed iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Hello I am making a html page were there are 3 spans that the user can click on and each span can change the iframe src below. Each span is associated with its own html page and when the span is clicked it changes the iframe to its own html page.

The problem is that each html page has its own buttons with different buttons and such and in my js file I tried to add .click() to each button and for some reason the only click() works for the main iframe that is the main src of the iframe before it is changed.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <span id="Frame1" class="bla">test 1</span> 
    <span id="Frame1" class="bla">test 2</span> 
    <span id="Frame3" class="bla">test3</span> 
</div>
<iframe src="test_1_Frame.html" style="width: 870px; height: 436px; border: 0;background-color:transparent;" id="frame">
```

Here is the code:

```
$(".bla").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#frame").attr("src", $(this).attr("id")+".html");
    let currentFrame = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(currentFrame);

    if (currentFrame == "Frame1") {
        console.log(currentFrame);


    } else if (currentFrame == "Frame2") {
        console.log(`${currentFrame} should be Frame2`);

    } else if (currentFrame == "Frame3") {
        console.log(`${currentFrame} should be Frame3`);

    }
});
```

then for the click part I did this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#frame1_button").click(function() {
        console.log('frame1');

    })
    $("#frame2_button").click(function() {
        console.log('frame2');

    })
     $("#frame3_button").click(function() {
        console.log('frame3');

    })
});
```

each of these buttons is its own different button in each frame HTML. but for some reason only the "frame1" logs in the console when I press the frame1_button, but when I press the frame2 or frame 3 button nothing logs in the console.

When I go into the console and try directly typing in to click the button nothing happens(button isn't pressed) and this is the response I get:

[image]

If anyone knows why this is happening I would really appreciate your help, Thanks in advance.

(also not a big issue but I would really like to change the background colour of the currently selected span so if anyone knows how to do that I would appreciate a answer or comment).

Comment: Do the pages that you are loading into the iframe have their own version of the jquery? If not you may have to use event delegation as those click listeners will only be applied to elements on the page at load time

Comment: Lol that fixed it thanks! @lucas

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    <span id="Frame1" onclick=doSomething(this)>test 1</span> 
    <span id="Frame2" onclick=doSomething(this)>test 2</span> 
    <span id="Frame3" onclick=doSomething(this)>test3</span> 
</div>

<script>
var doSomething = function(element){
console.log(element.id + " was clicked");
}
</script>
```

[With a code pen here..](https://codepen.io/carsnwd/pen/aQyMrL)

With `onclick` you can pass the element with `this`, and then access the id.

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem, I am displaying different html's and the button inside the html i switch to wont work or respond(the spans work fine)